# How to set an unknown number of elif statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below requires manual intervention every time I run it because the number of 'out_type_x' variables changes on every iteration. If I have 2 'out_type_x' variables then the code below works..

```
for counter, row in enumerate(df['out_type_1']):
    if 'A' in df['out_type_1'][counter]:
        for counter2, holder in enumerate(A_holders):
            holder.append(df[outcome_vars[counter2]+"1"][counter])
    elif 'A' in df['out_type_2'][counter]:
        for counter2, holder in enumerate(A_holders):
            holder.append(df[outcome_vars[counter2]+"2"][counter])
    else:
        for holder in A_holders:
            holder.append("NA")
```

..but if I have 3 'out_type_x' variables then I need to add another elif statement like this..

```
for counter, row in enumerate(df['out_type_1']):
    if 'A' in df['out_type_1'][counter]:
        for counter2, holder in enumerate(A_holders):
            holder.append(df[outcome_vars[counter2]+"1"][counter])
    elif 'A' in df['out_type_2'][counter]:
        for counter2, holder in enumerate(A_holders):
            holder.append(df[outcome_vars[counter2]+"2"][counter])
    elif 'A' in df['out_type_3'][counter]:
        for counter2, holder in enumerate(A_holders):
            holder.append(df[outcome_vars[counter2]+"3"][counter])
    else:
        for holder in A_holders:
            holder.append("NA")
```

Is there any way to change this code so that it doesn't require manual intervention every time? I can't get a loop to work because I can't break the if/else condition. As it stands I have to set the number of elif statements to the amount of 'out_type_x' variables I have, and it could be any number, leading to a long list of elif statements and the fact that the code requires manual intervention (which is not ideal).

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: How can you determine the number of `out_type_x` variables??

Comment: I can't, it's based on a number of files I receive from elsewhere, it varies a lot and always will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
for counter, row in enumerate(df['out_type_1']):
    for n in range(1, n_of_out_type_x+1):
        if 'A' in df[f'out_type_{n}'][counter]:
            for counter2, holder in enumerate(A_holders):
                holder.append(df[outcome_vars[counter2]+f"{n}"][counter])
            break
    else:
        for holder in A_holders:
            holder.append("NA")
```

Comment: Thank you, that works nicely. I had (for some reason) assumed that I couldn't use a for loop because I thought that I needed the elifs, I forgot about the break statement here. Cheers!